How to cancel the Flowable upstream's block logic when a TimeoutException throws
I have a rxjava2 code, like below:
public class Demo {

    /** @noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored*/
    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    public static void test() {
        Flowable.just(false).map(aBoolean -> block())
                .retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> {
                    AtomicInteger retryCounter = new AtomicInteger();
                    return throwableFlowable.takeWhile(throwable -> {
                        if (retryCounter.getAndIncrement() < 5) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        Exception exception;
                        try {
                            exception = (Exception) throwable;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            exception = new Exception(throwable);
                        }
                        throw exception;
                    });
                }).timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(aBoolean -> {
                    Log.e("Demo", "onNext");
                }, throwable -> {
                    Log.e("Demo", "onError", throwable);
                }, () -> {
                    Log.e("Demo", "onComplete");
                }, subscription -> {
                    subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                });
    }

    private static boolean block() {
        Log.e("Demo", "block");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // do nothing
        }
        Log.e("Demo", "block end");
        return true;
    }

}

When a TimeoutException throws, the block() method code still running, and the "block end" log will print after a while.
I have no idea. I expect that I could cancel the Flowable upstream's block logic when a TimeoutException throws. And even more I could make block method stop running! What can I try next?

Since the block() runs on the test thread and RxJava has no handle on it, there is no way in your setup a cancellation would unblock the chain.
To interrupt a blocking call in RxJava, you have to make sure it runs on a Scheduler. Thus, apply subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
However, the code would then fall off the test method so it is necessary to block on the result of the chain now:
Flowable.just(false)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // <--------------------------------
.map(aBoolean -> block())
.retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> {
     AtomicInteger retryCounter = new AtomicInteger();
     return throwableFlowable.takeWhile(throwable -> {
         if (retryCounter.getAndIncrement() < 5) {
             return true;
         }

         Exception exception;
         try {
             exception = (Exception) throwable;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             exception = new Exception(throwable);
         }
         throw exception;
     });
})
.timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.blockingSubscribe( // <------------------------------------------
                aBoolean -> {
                    Log.e("Demo", "onNext");
                }, throwable -> {
                    Log.e("Demo", "onError", throwable);
                }, () -> {
                    Log.e("Demo", "onComplete");
                });

